# Chrome for android hides address bar when scrolling, expands background image below footer

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, flask

I created a footer `#bottom_footer` that sticks to the bottom of the webpage when scrolling. It is set 100% from the top of the margin. It works fine on all browsers for desktop-view as well as for chrome on ios. However, on chrome for android, I get an issue where the background image of the body expands below the footer. This happens when the user scrolls down causing the address bar to hide but the webpage itself doesn't overflow the y-axis (it's displayed in full screen). I don't want to prevent the address bar from hiding, I want to prevent the background from expanding past the footer if the browser is in full-screen. I am developing this website in a flask app.

This code snippet requires Bootstrap 4.5 but I was having trouble getting the script and stylesheet to run. If anyone can add it in who knows how to add it into the code snippet, that would be much appreciated.

```css
body {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

#content-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#top_navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar_logo {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 6vw;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1b1b1b;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #1b1b1b;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-right: 3vw;
}

#bottom_footer,
#legal_documents {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: .4%;
}

#legal_documents {
  bottom: unset;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-bottom: .6% !important;
}

#social_buttons::selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons::-moz-selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bottom_footer a:hover,
#legal_documents a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="top_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" title="">
      <img id="navbar_logo" src="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_items" aria-controls="navbar_items" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_items">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main id="content-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
  </main>

  <div id="bottom_footer">
    <div id="social_buttons">
      <a href="" class="facebook" title="Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="instagram" title="Instagram" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="snapchat" title="Snapchat" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="youtube" title="YouTube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="legal_documents">
      <a href="" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">PRIVACY POLICY</a> |
      <a href="" title="Terms and Conditions" target="_blank">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You asked about Bootstrap CDN, here you go. Now will try to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATED

The direct answer for your question - there is a trick to correct `100vh` device height according to appearing and collapsing browser panels. Took from [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/).

```js
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);

// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

#content-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#top_navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar_logo {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 6vw;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1b1b1b;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #1b1b1b;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-right: 3vw;
}

#bottom_footer,
#legal_documents {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: .4%;
}

#legal_documents {
  bottom: unset;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-bottom: .6% !important;
}

#social_buttons::selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons::-moz-selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bottom_footer a:hover,
#legal_documents a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="top_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" title="">
      <img id="navbar_logo" src="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_items" aria-controls="navbar_items" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_items">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main id="content-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
  </main>

  <div id="bottom_footer">
    <div id="social_buttons">
      <a href="" class="facebook" title="Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="instagram" title="Instagram" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="snapchat" title="Snapchat" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="youtube" title="YouTube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="legal_documents">
      <a href="" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">PRIVACY POLICY</a> |
      <a href="" title="Terms and Conditions" target="_blank">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S. But I think there is a couple of core mistakes in your template. It's not a strict rules, only in my opinion.

1. Using `position: absolute;` for body. Can be replaced with `relative`.
2. Using for `body` `height: 100%;`. For better experience use `min-height: 100%;`
3. This part `#bottom_footer, #legal_documents` is very wrong, because it set same behavior for parent and child, which are `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`.
4. Your wish for `#top_navbar` and `#bottom_footerto` be sticky and a scrolling to *legal documents* are mutually exclusive.

I will write down one more version, rewrited according to my vision, but you can always use the firs one.

```js
setDimensions();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  setDimensions();
});

function setDimensions() {
  // this part is for prevent overlapping content by 'fixed' nav and footer, by adding 2 blocks with the same height, but with unset position 
  let topHeight = $('#top_navbar').outerHeight();
  let footerHeight = $('#bottom_footer').outerHeight();
  $('#pre_top_navbar').css('height', (topHeight) + 'px');
  $('#pre_bottom_footer').css('height', (footerHeight) + 'px');

  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

#content-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#top_navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar_logo {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 6vw;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1b1b1b;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #1b1b1b;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-right: 3vw;
}

#bottom_footer {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: .4%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#legal_documents {
  bottom: unset;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-bottom: .6% !important;
}

#social_buttons::selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons::-moz-selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}

#social_buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bottom_footer a:hover,
#legal_documents a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pre_top_navbar"></div>
  <nav id="top_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" title="">
      <img id="navbar_logo" src="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_items" aria-controls="navbar_items" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_items">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">LABEL</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main id="content-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    first<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>last
  </main>

  <div id="pre_bottom_footer"></div>
  <div id="bottom_footer">
    <div id="social_buttons">
      <a href="" class="facebook" title="Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="twitter" title="Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="instagram" title="Instagram" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="snapchat" title="Snapchat" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="" class="youtube" title="YouTube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="legal_documents">
      <a href="" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">PRIVACY POLICY</a> |
      <a href="" title="Terms and Conditions" target="_blank">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tested your suggestions in the mobile view of the website in chrome dev tools and it moves the top navigation bar down (it doesn't stick to the top of the window anymore). Also while there is scrolling, it doesn't scroll to the legal documents div (which is past 100% of the window's height). I updated my code to add the legal documents element so that you can see the scrolling and see what I am trying to do normally in a web view so it replicates the same functionality on android in chrome.

Comment: Found interesting solution for you. Even 2. Completely updated the answer. See please.

Comment: Why are the four things you mentioned core mistakes in my template? Why would they be considered issues? Do they cause problems in rendering, performance, loading, and/or user experience?

Comment: 1. `position: absolute;` uses when you need to put your element out of the parents and treat it some special way. Don's see any evidence to do it wit `body`. `relative` is enough. May it cause error? Maybe not, need to be tested. 2.If your content is higher than your body height - it will be scrolled more then 100% of body, while your `#bottom_footer` will stay on the 100% and overlay the body content. 3. Just very strange in my opinion and a lot of unnecessary code. 4. Better to choose, if you want a scroll to `legal_documents` or to have a sticky footer.

Comment: But, as I said - these are not strict rules, but my vision of this tusk. I don't see all context of your app and can't observe it in real conditions. So you may know better and ignore it. Anyway, there is a firs Snippet that demonstrates you how to solve you problem using JS.

Comment: Your answer worked for me thanks! I haven't implemented any of your four suggestions yet but I did notice on mobile that scrolling of the page, which results in removing the address bar in mobile, is not very smooth. Could this be an android chrome bug or something wrong with the code I have provided?

Comment: About not very smooth result - it's probably Android Chrome feature. You can try to add `body {transition: height .25s ease;}`, and your height changes will be more smooth. P.S. this part `height: 100vh;  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);` was not a double, but for some older browsers, which doesn't support `calc()` or `var()`.

Comment: Ah I didnt know about that. I mean there's a very low percentage of people who use old browsers anyway, so I'm not too concerned about that. Anyone who still uses IE should not be using IE, many security risks.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables and https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc and https://www.stetic.com/market-share/browser/ if you are curious.

Comment: Is there an automated application out there of some kind to see if my HTML/CSS/JS code or website is supported on all browsers and the versions of those browsers? Preferably would not want to upload the code online but download some application or add-on to an IDE that does that, would be super helpful.

Comment: Sounds like your next question on SO ;) Do not know much about it, sorry.